# How to use Nested States & Views correctly?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

this is my page structure:

```
        root URL '/home'
        -> toolbar
            -> tool1
            -> tool2
        -> menuLeft
        -> menuRight
        -> content of home
```

How would I write the `home` state?
How would look another route lets say `about`, if the toolbar, menuLeft and menuRight are the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If toolbar, menu left and menu right are the same across pages, then they should be defined in the main HTML template, and each of them can have their own controller so they can manage their states independently of application states defined in `ui-router`:

```
<body>
    <div id="toolbar" ng-controller="ToolbarCtrl"> ... </div>
    <div id="left" ng-controller="LeftMenuCtrl"> ... </div>

    <div id="content" ui-view>
        <!-- content here depends on what you configure in ui-router -->
        <!-- home.html for 'home' state, and 'about.html' for 'about' state -->
    </div>

    <div id="right" ng-controller="RightMenuCtrl"> ... </div>
</body>
```

Here is one way to configure your states:

```
app.config(function($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider.state('home', {
        url: '/',
        templateUrl: 'src/app/content/home.html',
        controller: 'HomeCtrl'
    }).state('about', {
        url: '/about',
        templateUrl: 'src/app/content/about.html',
        controller: 'AboutCtrl'
    });
});
```

Noted that if you define controller in each state (i.e., 'HomeCtrl', 'AboutCtrl'), it will be applied to the whole page automatically when you navigate to such state -- you don't need `ng-controller` for it.

Answer (score 0):

```
function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
      when('/toolbar/:toolNumber', { // here toolnumber is a optional parameter
        templateUrl: 'partials/toolbar.html',
        controller: 'toolbarCtrl'
      }).
      when('/menuLeft', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/menuLeft.html',
        controller: 'menuLeftCtrl'
      }).
      when('/menuRight', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/menuRight.html',
        controller: 'menuRightCtrl'
      }).
      otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/home'
      });
  }]);
```